# Does AudioKit v5 include any “third party analytics” code?

Tags: ios, app-store, analytics, appstore-approval, audiokit

Note: I know the App Store is considered off topic for Stack Overflow, but this question does seem to address code.

I am trying to submit an app to the App Store but I am not sure if I am complying with the Apple Guidelines.

I received a message from Apple asking if my app includes any “third party analytics,” but I am unsure of the answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: afaik no, it doesn’t call home or anything. but ianal and tinla. you could check your app with a firewall or some other means of watching network traffic.

Comment: Appreciate the response @mahaltertin